# Checking network connection status in Cordova and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

It's a basic question as I'm beginner in both Cordova and AngularJS.
I have an application with `Cordova` and `AngulaJS` and I want to check network connectivity using [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) in an angular way.

The below code works fine:

```
var app = angular.module('CordovaPluginTest', []);
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        document.addEventListener('online', toggleCon, false);
        document.addEventListener('offline', toggleCon, false);
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE)
            $rootScope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.isOnline = false; });
        else
            $rootScope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.isOnline = true; });
    }, false);

    function toggleCon(e) {
        if (e.type == 'online')
            $rootScope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.isOnline = true; });
        else if (e.type == 'offline')
            $rootScope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.isOnline = false; });
    }
}])
```

But the below one does not work:

```
var app = angular.module('CordovaPluginTest', []);
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('deviceready', function () {
        $rootScope.$on('online', function () { $rootScope.isOnline = true; });
        $rootScope.$on('offline', function () { $rootScope.isOnline = false; });
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE)
                $rootScope.isOnline = false;
        else
                $rootScope.isOnline = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$watch('isOnline', function (val) { alert('watch isOnline:'+val);})
}])
```

Why defining `angular event listener` doesn't work? In fact it doesn't get the event at all!
What is the correct way of doing this in angular?

Comment: Why not using ngCordova which is a module wrapping Cordova plugins in an Angular way (see http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/)?

Comment: You are getting it wrong `$rootScope.$on` isn't alias of `document.addEventListener`, Angular uses its own event registration using `$broadcast`/`$emit`, [read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) here

Comment: @beaver I  have seen that before, because of  compatibility issues in future probably and because I want to understand the concepts better this way.

Comment: @rahilwazir , As I understand $broadcast/$emit is to trigger an event, but I'm not triggering online/offline, it's triggering outside angular.

Comment: So, as $rootScope.$on is for angular own registering event, how should I do this in angular? Is the first code the only way of doing this?

Comment: You can also use `$document.on("event-type",function( event ){ ...  });` or `angular.element(document).bind("event-type",function( event ){ ... });` to attach an handler to document, but this is a jQuery/jqLite "way"... But surely you can't use `$rootScope.$on` to listen to an event attached to document element.

Comment: Thanks @beaver, As you said it is jQuery way. I'm looking for AngularJS way :)

Comment: Yes, but for [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) Angular uses a wrapper and to [bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) relating events it relies on jQuery/jqLite

Comment: @beaver, replacing `$rootScope.$on` with `$document.on` and also using `$rootScope.$apply` in event callback function works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `document` DOM element Angular uses a wrapper ([$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24document)) and to bind relating events it relies on [jQuery/jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

So you can use `$document.on("event-type",function( event ){ ... });` or `angular.element(document).bind("event-type",function( event ){ ... });` to attach an handler to `document`.

But surely you can't use $rootScope.$on to listen to an event attached to document element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 app.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
  $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.online = false;
//        $window.location.reload();
    });
  }, false);
  $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.online = true;
 //       $window.location.reload();
    });
  }, false);
});
```

And add network information plugin in cordova